# Can't install NVIDIA apex on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, nvidia, apex

I want to install Nvidia Apex on Windows 10 machine with Python 3.6.8. Im doing the `git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex`, install requirements then `pip install -v --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" .` as being said on their github page. Unfortunately, all the times among other logs i get the error:

```
Cleaning up...
Removing source in C:\Users\popie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-okoz8ok5
Removed build tracker 'C:\\Users\\popie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-35lh6btm'
Command ""c:\program files\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools,tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\popie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-okoz8ok5\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n','\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" --cpp_ext --cuda_ext install --record C:\Users\popie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qmhcg5oq\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\popie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-okoz8ok5\    

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 366, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 49, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 791, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 705, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command ""c:\program files\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\popie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-okoz8ok5\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" --cpp_ext --cuda_ext install --record C:\Users\popie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qmhcg5oq\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\popie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-okoz8ok5\

Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect

Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
```

I've tried fixes from what google told me to do, but none of them works.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Info in https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex#windows-support. I was able to install minimal version(without CUDA/C++ extensions) using command "pip install -v --no-cache-dir ."